# Zend Form : development preview

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

If I use zend form in the development of view all. I can see a preview page when developing or not.

code example :

**form : ProductForm.php**

```
$this->setName('product_form');
$this->addElement('text','product_name',array(
'label'=>'product name :',
'required'=>true,
'validators'=>'NotEmpty',
));
```

**Controller : ProductController.php**

```
$form = new ProductForm();
$this->view->form = $form;
```

**Views : index.phtml**

`<'?php echo $this->form ;?>`' // ok. i want to see a preview page when developing

Comment: can you please explain your question again?

Comment: What do you mean by "a preview page"?

Comment: example : index.phtml Like the design of dreamweaver. can't see design index.phtml

Comment: if you call your controller action maybe: http://localhost/product/index you should see the form rendered in your browser

Answer (score 0):

If you want a preview mode which disallow the fields to be modified, you can use the helper 'formNote' on the elements of your form.